# Hitting stored proc - javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, ejb

I'm trying to hit a stored procedure but I'm getting this error message: 'javax.ejb.EJBException'... I've never worked with stored procedures so the exception is a bit Greek to me.

Anyone that could perhaps shed some light on this? Below I pasted the code that I wrote:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getSpecimenResultsXml")
public String getSpecimenResultsXml(@WebParam(name = "specimenGuid") String specimenGuid, @WebParam(name = "publicationGuid") String publicationGuid, @WebParam(name = "forProvider") String forProvider) {

    //Method variables
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String xml = null;

    // 1) get server connection
    Connection conn = dataBaseConnection.getConnection();

    // 2) Pass recieved parameters to stored proc.
    try {
        CallableStatement proc =
                conn.prepareCall("{ call getSpecimenReportXml(?, ?, ?) }");
        proc.setString(1, specimenGuid);
        proc.setString(2, publicationGuid);
        proc.setString(3, forProvider);
        proc.execute();

        rs = proc.getResultSet();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("--------------Error in getSpecimenResultsXml------------");
        System.out.println("Cannot call stored proc: " + e);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    // 3) Get String from result set
    try {
        xml = rs.getString(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("--------------Error in getSpecimenResultsXml------------");
        System.out.println("Cannot retrieve result set: " + e);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    // 4) close connection
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("--------------Error in getSpecimenResultsXml------------");
        System.out.println("Cannot close connection: " + e);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    // 5) return the returned String
    return xml;
}
```

Oh and the stored procedure us called **getSpecimenReportXml**...

Comment: The exception is a mystery to us, too, since we can't see it. Ugh; those comments are noise, and please use logging instead of S.o.p.s.

Comment: Apparently it was caused by a NullPointerException. But again, I don't know where it would've occurred. If you want the full exception, I could post it? But it's quite a couple of lines. For the comments, it won't stay there, it's just there for now to help me keep track. When I commit my changes to our CVS then I'll take them out... But that's besides the point...

Comment: There's absolutely no way for anybody to help without seeing the actual error.

Comment: (Although I'll say this; your code just plows ahead if there *is* an exception, which makes the exception handling perhaps informative, but ultimately non-functional.)

Comment: The exception and the stored procedure definition will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception would say 'caused by' somewhere - which is a big clue. If it's an NPE then you might want to check the values of `dataBaseConnection` and `conn` to make sure they've been set. Use a debugger to do this, but the exception should tell you exactly which line caused the problem.